# Swift Error: Statements are not allowed at the top level

Tags: json, swift

I'm going through the Argo documentation for Swift JSON Parsing (https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo) and they provide a simple code snippet that should retrieve the JSON data, but I get an error when running it. The snippet is:

```
// Wherever you receive JSON data:

let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil)

if let j: AnyObject = json {
  let user: User? = decode(j)
}
```

and the error I get is "Statements are not allowed at the top level", on the line that says if let j...

Why would this cause an error and why is this in their github readme if it doesn't work?

Comment: Where are you putting those lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it is a snippet. You are expected to use it *inside a function*, where it is legal. Executable code can appear only in a function.

Comment: Basically they are assuming you know the basics of Swift.

Comment: Actually, just rename the file "main.swift" and swift will run through like a script and execute top-level code just fine, that's how it enters program execution.  However, this particular snippet is not self-contained and it would still complain about 'data' being undefined.